# Convert timestamp to datetime changing format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `timestamp` `2020-01-08T16:06:00+00:00` format value, I want to convert it to `datetime` format as **`2020-01-08 16:06:00`**.

I have tried to convert to `datetime`, but getting error says:

> failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I would like to convert `timestamp` to `datetime`.

Comment: What is the **actual data-type** of your "timestamp" value? Note that you generally should not perform date and time formatting operations in SQL because it's not a storage concern.

Comment: Seeing as how you have an offset there, even though it's zero, try converting to `datetimeoffset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the timezone, you can use:

```
select convert(datetime, left('2020-01-08T16:06:00+00:00', 19))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply interested in dropping the the offset, and not converting the timestamp to local time (as the offset sets the timestamp at UTC), try this:

```sql
DECLARE @timestamp AS DATETIMEOFFSET = '2020-01-08T16:06:00+00:00' ;
SELECT  CAST ( @timestamp AS DATETIME2(0) ) AS formatted_timestamp ;
```

(I've assumed the data type for your timestamp is DATETIMEOFFSET. But this could also work if the data type is DATETIME or DATETIME2.)